# Finding the item count in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to find the number of nulls for a col_name. I am using the code below in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @NumNull INT = N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @WhichTable + N' WHERE col_name IS NULL'
```

I have declared `@WhichTable` as NVARCHAR(MAX) at the beginning of my procedure.

I am getting this error message:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_FILL_CHAIN_NAMES, Line 22
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UNION_ALL WHERE col_name IS NULL' to data type int.

I am not sure how to rewrite this SQL code? I tried `exec()`, and even SQL but it does not seem to be working!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263801/sql-server-dynamic-queries)

Comment: All your tables have a column called col_name?

Comment: Clearly it's a string.  Why do you declare your variable as an `INT`?

Comment: Maybe Google how to do dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use sp_executesql to assign result from a dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @WhichTable nvarchar(max)= 'Categories'
declare @NumNull int 
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

Set @sql = 'SELECT @NumNull = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @WhichTable + ' WHERE CategoryId IS NOT NULL';
execute sp_executesql 
    @sql, 
    N'@NumNull int OUTPUT', 
    @NumNull = @NumNull output;
select @NumNull;
```

Comment: Thank you for the code demonstration. I read about sp_executesql, but I'm sort of new to Transact SQL code. Your code demonstrates to me what the essential elements of this sp are.

Answer (score 2):

You trying to store whole SELECT statement in an int variable, not the result of your select.

You need to:

1. Store your SQL in NVARCHAR variable.
2. Use sp_executesql to execute it.

Good example how to do it is available there:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/262499/how-to-specify-output-parameters-when-you-use-the-sp-executesql-stored